# Check if an radio button was checked and finding out which

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, radio-button

**Hello Guys and have a great friday ! :)**

1: I am building a .net site for school , and I would like to build a survey , which you should check one of the options (radio inputs) and click 'vote'.

I built a form this way :

```
<form runat="server">
    <div id="voteBox">
        <h3 class="heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="messi" GroupName="players" /><h5 class="text">מסי</h5>
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="iniesta" CssClass="iniesta" GroupName="players" /><h5 class="text" style="margin-right: 50px; margin-top: -20px;">איניאסטה</h5>
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="xavi" CssClass="xavi" GroupName="players" /><h5 class="text" style="margin-right: 50px; margin-top: -20px;">צאבי</h5>
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="pedro" CssClass="pedro" GroupName="players" /><h5 class="text" style="margin-right: 50px; margin-top: -20px;">פדרו</h5>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text=" הצבע " cssClass="submitButt" style="margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 210px;" onClick="countVote" />
    </div>
</form>
```

From this , how may I find out if one of the options was chosen when clicking the button , and than finding put which was it that was chosen .

2: In order to keep the votes in the server , I would like to use Application variables . Can you please guide me on how to make those variables and raising their's value as one of the options is chosen and voted.

Thank you in advance, 
Iliya

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using vb.net, then you will have a submit_countVote sub (procedure) in your code behind. You can then use the code beneath:

```
Protected Sub submit_countVote(Object Sender, EventArgs e)

  if messi.checked then 
      if Application("messi") is nothing then     
         Application("messi") = 0
      end if
    Application("messi") = Cint(Application("messi")) + 1
  End if
  'Repeat for rediobutton
End Sub
```

Although you know have an in memory counter, this counters will disappear when the application gets recycled (once a day depending on the settings) or when it crashes. You should look for examples on saving it to a database.